# How to inject a google app engine 'user' from android client side?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-authentication

Say for example an endpoint of mine takes (User user) from the backed. How can i inject this 'user' from my android client side using google authentication to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here at GAE injected types:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#injected_types

If you are using Google's authentication, the User will be injected automatically into the Endpoints API method and then you can do things like check if the user exists (in your datastore for example), save the user to datastore, etc.

The way it works is in your Android client the user gets prompted to sign into their Google account via oAuth2.0 and once they do, the GoogleAccountCredential object gets passed into the builder.

Here is example code taken from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android):

```
// Inside your Activity class onCreate method
settings = getSharedPreferences("TicTacToeSample", 0);
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
    "server:client_id:1-web-app.apps.googleusercontent.com");
setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

Tictactoe.Builder builder = new Tictactoe.Builder(
    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(),
    credential);
service = builder.build();

if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() != null) {
  // Already signed in, begin app!
} else {
  // Not signed in, show login window or request an account.
}

// setSelectedAccountName definition
private void setSelectedAccountName(String accountName) {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
  editor.commit();
  credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
  this.accountName = accountName;
}
```

Basically some magic happens and Cloud Endpoints now is able to inject the logged in User into your Endpoints method. And you can check if it is null or not (if null, auth is no good so throw an unauthorized error), get that user's email, etc.

Hope that gets you started.